# Trying to build HTML elements by code, functions included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first post, hoping someone can help me:

I wish to build a web project, where all the HTML elements are stored in database and taken from it to build the web page.

i found a problem with the buttons, i cannot find a way to store the function for a button, i´m using Jquery to build the elements, for now the test element definitions are simulated in some arrays i left at the start of my Js file, the only way i can make the buttons to work is if the functions are hardcoded in the Js file, is there a way for me to bring the functions from database too? and having them in an array?

this is my project sample:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="functions.js"></script-->
<script src="system.js"></script>
<!--script src="elements.js"></script-->

</head>
<body>

<body onload="addElements()">

  <div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS File

```
/**
VARIABLE DEFINITIONS
THESE ARE SUPPOSED TO COME FROM A DATABASE
STILL UNKNOWN HOW TO BRING THE FUNCTIONS, AS STRING THEY ARE NOT ALLOWED. FOR NOW THERE ARE TEST FUNCTIONS.
**/

let buttonIds = ['btn1', 'btn2'];
let buttonText = ['Show Text', 'Show HTML'];
let buttonFunc = [alert1, alert2];
//let buttonFunc = ['alert("Hi");', 'alert("Hello");'];
let paragraphs = ['This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.', 'another <b>bold</b> test'];


//HELPER FUNCTIONS
// **** THESE ARE SUPPOSED TO COME FROM DATABASE, UNKNOWN HOW TO DO IT. ****

function alert1() {
    alert("Hi");
}

function alert2(){
    alert("Hello");
}




function addElements(){ 
    for(var p=0; p<paragraphs.length; p++){ addParagraphs('#div1', paragraphs[p]);                  }
    for(var i=0; i<buttonIds.length; i++) { createButton( '#div1', buttonIds[i]  , buttonText[i]);  }
}

// ANY ELEMENTS FUNCTION IS DEFINED HERE ONCE THE PAGE IS LOADED.
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var x=0;x<buttonIds.length; x++){ activateButton(buttonIds[x], buttonFunc[x]); }
});


//HELPER FUNCTIONS USED TO BUILD THE HTML ELEMENTS ON THE MAIN PAGE.
function addParagraphs(location, text){
  $(location).append('<p id="test">'+text+'</p>');
}


function createButton(location, id, text){
var definition;

definition = "<button id="+id+">"+text+"</button>";
$(location).append(definition);
}


function activateButton(buttonId, functionName){
  var composedId = "#"+buttonId;
    $(composedId).click(functionName);
}
```

Comment: How are these functions supposed to be generated and added to database? What is the higher level use case for all of this? This very well could be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Technically you could turn your whole JS file into a string and run it in a seperate file or `script` tag. But that does not seem like a good practice. Could explain more on the *why* of this question?

Comment: I agree with the other comments. This really doesn't sound like a scalable or performant way to solve a problem. What exactly is your goal here? Separation of concerns is a big part of any design. By storing the HTML elements and the JS functions in your DB, you completely obliterate separation of concerns. Let the DB be for your data. Let an HTML file define the structure and semantics of your data. Let CSS handle your presentation. And let JS handle your behavior.

Comment: U guys are right, i didn´t provide enought information, so let me explain the context:
I work in a company that uses a platform that creates web applications, its interface has its menu, right pannel and reports. it also has an administration section where i can define a button, give it a name, define position {menu, right pannel, or inside a report}, i can create the button and then i can give it its function in its own editor. i understand that everithing i created is saved into database and built in the Web application when it´s displayed.
So i want to do something symilar in my own way.

Comment: until now, Jquery allows me to take almost everything from tha database: name, Id, even button´s text, but i cannot put the function for it from an array as the other elements because the code recognizes the function as a string and not a function, even if the text is the same. that´s why i´m stuck.
Some will say: ask the guy who built the platform. i already tried, maybe they don´t have the time, maybe they want to protect their product, anyway, i´m trying to find a way, for now i only know this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Javascript file serverside with all the funcions you need.
Supposing Node.js you can do something like this:

```
expressApp.get("some.js", (req, res) => {
  getDataFromDatabase() // depends on your database
  .then(data => {
    let body = 'function your_fn () { alert("'+ JSON.stringify(data) +'")}';
    res.send(body);
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is use an object to store the functions in javascript and use property names stored in db to associate which function to use for which element.

Without knowing more about your use case it is hard to really help design a proper system to use

Following is a very basic example

```js
// functions stored in js file
const funcs = {
    f1: function(e){ console.log('func one called , id = ', this.id)},
    f2: function(e){ console.log('func 2 called , id = ', this.id)}
}

// data from database
const elems = [
   {id: 1, className: 'one', func:'f1', text:'Item 1'},
   {id: 1, className: 'two', func:'f2', text:'Item 2'}
]

elems.forEach(e => {
   const $el= $('<div>', {id: e.id, class: e.className, text:e.text, click: funcs[e.func]})
   $('body').append($el);
});
```

```css
div {margin:1em;}
.one {color:red;}
.two {color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Click on items</strong><br><br>
```

Comment: i like the way your example is coded, from what i see it´s difficult (or maybe imposible) to store the functions for a button in database, but having pre-defined functions that uses parameters taken from database is possible based on this example, this options still has limited capabilities but thanks to this i´m closer now, thanks.